# Biztalk Dehydrated orchestrations

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2010, biztalk-orchestrations

In my application, there are long running orchestrations waiting for response from other systems and these orchestrations dehydrate when no response is received. i.e. there is sometimes a big no of dehydrated orchestrations which can lead to performance issues. I am trying to change this design so that orchestration is completed after sending to the other system. But, when the response is received, I need to relate this (i.e subscribe) to the orchestration already completed (orchestration that sent to other system). Which is the best way of doing this in BizTalk.

Answer (score 0):

It is more that the response from the other (second) system needs to contain all the information you need to spin up a new Orchestration and send the response back to the originating system.  Then you don't need to have a long running Orchestration that dehydrates.

If that is not possible you may need to persist the needed information into a database table and look it up again when you receive the response.